# How can I run a custom script on /usr/bin/ via cronjob?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, cron, desktop-background, i3-wm

### First of all:

This is not a duplicated of [Cronjobs made via cronjob not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350541/cronjobs-made-via-cronjob-not-working) which seems to be fixed by simply giving execution permissions to the script and/or adding the `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the script.

I have tried some advices published on the net, forums and other but I haven't yet succeeded.

## The scenery:

I am experiencing some issues when attempting to run custom scripts located on `/usr/bin` via cronjob. In example: I am using Ubuntu 14.04.3 with the i3WM Tiling Window Manager, in which I am trying to run a custom script named `wall` which should change the wallpaper with `feh` via command line.

The wall script does run well when it is invoked via terminal or the i3wm menu bar, which indicates the script should run, but, it does not.

### The script

When I find for the `wall` script via `whereis wall`, the terminal shows the next results:

```
wall: /usr/bin/wall /usr/bin/X11/wall /usr/share/man/man1/wall.1.gz
```

I am not sure why do I have a copy of the script both on the `/usr/bin` and the `/usr/bin/X11` directories but both them do the same when I run it manually. Neither one or the other do anything when I put it on the crontab.

The script contents is as follows:

```
feh --bg-scale "`shuf -n1 -e ~/.i3/wall/*`"
```

This command is going to get a random image from the ~/.i3/wall folder and scale that image to desktop's size in order to be used as a background image.

The script file properties looks like this:

```
geppettvs@T400:~$ ls /usr/bin -l | grep wall
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root      root       2067448 oct 21  2013 fotowall
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root      root          6264 oct 27 09:21 kwalletd
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root      tty             45 ene 27 07:51 wall
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root      root          1747 abr 25  2014 wallpaper-changer
```

Of which I just notice the property differs just by the "tty" in the script, which I changed to root via `chown` with no difference at all.

### The crontab

My user's crontab currently contains the next:

```
GNU nano 2.2.6 File: /tmp/crontab.Fb84OE/crontab                                                                            

# m h  dom mon dow   command
# * * * * * /home/geppettvs/wifirc.sh # JOB_ID_2
* * * * * /usr/bin/wall # JOB_ID_4
```

My root user crontab looks like this:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command

@reboot sudo iwconfig wlan0 rate 54M
* * * * * wall
```

But, neither the user's crontab or the root one does anything with this script.

Let's have in mind that, this time, I am talking about a simple wallpaper changer script. But I have some other scripts that won't run when I put them in a crontab.

### Additional attempts

I have already tried using the `#!/bin/bash` in the first line of the script, leaving or removing blank lines at the top/bottom of the script and/or the crontab file. And it seems not to have effect to make it work. The same goes for trying to use the absolute path or invoking the script simply by name (which works on a terminal, indeed).

### The Log

The Log looks like this:

```
Feb 13 17:20:01 T400 CRON[9093]: (geppettvs) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x00ff, #012)
Feb 13 17:20:01 T400 CRON[9094]: (root) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x00ff, #012)
Feb 13 17:21:01 T400 CRON[10290]: (geppettvs) CMD (/usr/bin/wall # JOB_ID_4)
Feb 13 17:21:01 T400 CRON[10291]: (root) CMD (wall)
Feb 13 17:21:01 T400 CRON[10289]: (root) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x00ff, #012)
Feb 13 17:21:01 T400 CRON[10288]: (geppettvs) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x00ff, #012)
Feb 13 17:22:01 T400 CRON[11575]: (geppettvs) CMD (/usr/bin/wall # JOB_ID_4)
Feb 13 17:22:01 T400 CRON[11578]: (root) CMD (wall)
Feb 13 17:22:01 T400 CRON[11573]: (geppettvs) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x00ff, #012)
Feb 13 17:22:01 T400 CRON[11574]: (root) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x00ff, #012)
Feb 13 17:23:01 T400 CRON[12860]: (geppettvs) CMD (/usr/bin/wall # JOB_ID_4)
Feb 13 17:23:01 T400 CRON[12862]: (root) CMD (wall)
Feb 13 17:23:01 T400 CRON[12859]: (root) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x00ff, #012)
Feb 13 17:23:01 T400 CRON[12858]: (geppettvs) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x00ff, #012)
Feb 13 17:24:01 T400 CRON[14157]: (root) CMD (wall)
Feb 13 17:24:01 T400 CRON[14158]: (geppettvs) CMD (/usr/bin/wall # JOB_ID_4)
Feb 13 17:24:01 T400 CRON[14155]: (geppettvs) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x00ff, #012)
Feb 13 17:24:01 T400 CRON[14156]: (root) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x00ff, #012)
Feb 13 17:25:01 T400 CRON[15448]: (geppettvs) CMD (/usr/bin/wall # JOB_ID_4)
Feb 13 17:25:01 T400 CRON[15450]: (root) CMD (wall)
Feb 13 17:25:01 T400 CRON[15447]: (root) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x00ff, #012)
Feb 13 17:25:01 T400 CRON[15446]: (geppettvs) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x00ff, #012)
```

Which seems to be running the script but nothing is happening on each scripts run iteration.

### The question

Is it there something wrong I am doing? Or something else I should try?

Any help is appreciated.

## Update

As mentioned in a comment for **j0h's** advice, I have also tried using the absolute path to the image's folder.

The command now looks like

```
feh --bg-scale "`shuf -n1 -e /home/geppettvs/.i3/wall/*`"
```

and it does work on a terminal but doesn't run via cron.

I am guessing the issue comes from the grave accent (`) which can be leading to an interruption in the cronjob's execution.

Nevertheless, I have tried changing the grave accent for another symbol, after which the command stops working everywhere. You can see terminal's output as shown:

```
geppettvs@T400:~$ feh --bg-scale "'shuf -n1 -e /home/geppettvs/.i3/wall/*'" 
feh WARNING: 'shuf -n1 -e /home/geppettvs/.i3/wall/*' does not exist - skipping
feh: No loadable images specified.
See 'man feh' for detailed usage information
```

Any help for improving this command is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `wall` is perhaps an unfortunate choice of name for a custom script, since there is already a standard system utility called `wall`

Comment: why is there a "sudo" in your cron?!?!

Comment: @Rinzwind: As I mentioned before, I have tried many things. Including the most ridiculous we can think about. :D

Comment: @steeldriver I have already changed the name of wall in order to avoid name collisions with no results. The renamed script is now wall-change. My luck should be the worst in the world if there is a standard system utility called wall-change. Thank you for the advice. I didn't notice it before. I appreciate your help.

Comment: when you run `feh --bg-scale "`shuf -n1 -e ~/.i3/wall/*`"` is the tilda your home, or roots? what if you make that Tilda the absolute path you want to specify?

Comment: @j0h: I have also tried that. The command now looks like feh --bg-scale "`shuf -n1 -e /home/geppettvs/.i3/wall/*`" and it does work on a terminal but doesn't run via cron. I am guessing the issue comes from the grave accent (`) which can be leading to an interruption in the cronjob's execution. Nevertheless, I have tried changing the grave accent for another symbol, after which the command stops working everywhere.  I am going to put this in an edit in an attempt to gather some help improving this command. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you specify the display that feh uses? when root goes to run the cronjob, it doesnt know what display your on. It might default to display:0.0.
maybe try setting up the cronjob, on the display youll use. like this:
`*/3 * * * * DISPLAY=:0.0 scritp.sh`  or whatever something like that.

Comment: Yes. That's it. I'll appreciate a lot if you add your suggestion to use the display trick as an answer in order to accept it as a solution, as this seems to fix the issue when it is about this kind of scripts which affects something on a defined display. Thank you very much @j0h! and many Thanks to all the people who provided some help.